How to generate a .skey file
I've minted some tokens using the JS library lucid. To add these to the Cardano token registry I need to use a .skey file. Is there a way to generate this with lucid? Or another library perhaps?

you could use lucid, as outlined in

generate-credentilas.ts script

here
